# Python OpenPyxl: Create a Line Chart from data arranged in columns

Tags: python, excel, charts, openpyxl

[image: Data in Excel]

I'm trying to build a linechart with `Opepyxl`. The target is to have a line charts which shows the Std.dev trend for the items in the first row (gap1MachiSide, Gap1OperatorSide etc..);

Here my code:

```
#Create a linechart for std.dev
chart1 = LineChart()
chart1.style = 10

chart1.title = "Gap MC-OP Std.Dev"
chart1.y_axis.title = 'St.Dev [mm]'
chart1.x_axis.title = 'Gap #'


data = Reference(ws2, min_col=2, min_row=3, max_row=3, max_col=35)

chart1.add_data(data)

s1= chart1.series[0]
s1.marker.symbol = "triangle"

chart1.dataLabels = DataLabelList()
chart1.dataLabels.showVal = True
chart1.shape = 30
chart1.width = 35
chart1.height = 7

ws2.add_chart(chart1, "A10")
```

Comment: c.add_data(from_rows=True) controls how the series are interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

The openpyxl documentation discusses building charts with data in columns, but not rows. I have the same problem -- openpyxl does not seem to support data in rows.

There are no arguments in Series() to specify data by rows instead of columns. Apparently it assumes data is in colums and loses the valid data when it pops the data series name. I haven't tried it, but it might also work to simply not use the title_from_data argument.

What worked for me was to change the series.val field to the desired row range, after calling add_data() or the Series constructor. Note that using title_from_data=True pops the first cell out of the Reference range_string, changing it to just the data cell range.

Because openpyxl uses fairly strong typing in its internal structures, I needed to use a number of type coercions to make this work.

Replace these two lines:

```
data = Reference(ws2, min_col=2, min_row=3, max_row=3, max_col=35)
chart1.add_data(data)
```

with these five lines:

```
from openpyxl.chart.data_source import NumRef, NumDataSource
data = Reference(ws2, min_col=2, min_row=3, max_row=3, max_col=35)   #no change
chart1.add_data(data)                                                #no change
data_range = str(data)
chart1.series[-1].val = NumDataSource(NumRef(data_range))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace:

```
chart1.add_data(data)
```

with

```
chart1.add_data(data, from_rows=True)
```

it should work (I'm using openpyxl 3.0.3).
[image]